# I have an infinite for loop but I cant find which part of my code is causing it

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, infinite-loop, josephus

I am trying to solve the Josephus problem with an ArrayList and for loops. I have created an infinite for loop within my circle.size for loop but I cant deduce which part of my code is causing it to happen.

```
public class project1 {
  public static int Josephus (int n, int k){                                     
    ArrayList<Integer> circle = new ArrayList<Integer>();                       
    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {                                              
      circle.add(p);                                                            
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + n + " people in the circle.");            
    System.out.println(circle);                                                 

    ArrayList<Integer> kill_order = new ArrayList<Integer>();                   
    for (int index=1; circle.size()!=1; index++){                               
      if (circle.size() > 1){                                                   
        index = (index + k - 1) % circle.size();                                
        kill_order.add(index);                                                  
        circle.remove((Integer)index);
        System.out.println(kill_order);
      } else if (circle.size()==1){
        System.out.println("Execution Order: " + kill_order + " ");
        System.out.println(kill_order);
        index = 1;
      }
    }
    return circle.get(0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You should sit in seat " + Josephus(7, 2) + " if you want to survive!");
  }
}
```

Comment: With an empty circle, or when the size == 1 it becomes problematic. Debugging would have helped.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. doscio has a correct answer for you. I highly recommend learning to use a debugger. That way you can step through your code and see how the variables are changing as you pass through the `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the problem is related to this line of code  `circle.remove((Integer)index);`

if you replace with `circle.remove(index)` the programs end without any infinite loop.

If you call the method `circle.remove((Integer) index)` it search an element inside the array with that value, the method `circle.remove(index)` it remove the element at the specified index.

See the javadoc for additional details [remove(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) [remove(Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Comment: In your second sentence, did you mean to write `circle.remove(index)`?

Comment: @dave Yes, fixed :)

Comment: @doscio I initially had circle.remove(index) but if you look at one of my earlier questions 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105185/i-do-not-understand-why-i-am-seeing-an-index-from-my-array-list-twice-despite-ha

the index does not get removed.

Answer (score 1):

Every next iteration of your main loop looks like:

| index at the beginning of the loop | index after assign new value | circle array |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 1, 3, 5, 6, 7 |
| 5 | 1 | 3, 5, 6, 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 5, 6, 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 5, 6, 7 - it cannot remove value 2 and array is not size 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 5, 6, 7 |
| 2 | 0 | 5, 6, 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 5, 6, 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 5, 6, 7 - cycle starts to repeat |

So probably your algorithm is wrong, or you should remove element at index, not by value `(circle.remove(index))` - without converting it to `Integer`